# How to convert a CSV into a nested JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, csv, csvtojson, nested-json

So i have read alot of previous questions about this topic but non were really able to help me get to the result I want so here's the CSV file sample

```
tripId,scooterId,userId,totalDuration,pickUpTime,dropOffTime,userLocationAtBooking.0,userLocationAtBooking.1,userLocationAtDropOff.0,userLocationAtDropOff.1,totalFare
18721,927,38579,45,2021-08-22 03:00:49,2021-08-22 03:45:39,24.76412,46.6493,24.76409833,46.64934,9.58
18722,434,38563,45,2021-08-22 03:01:16,2021-08-22 03:45:39,24.76412,46.64933333,24.76407,46.64933333,13.53
18723,876,38554,33,2021-08-22 03:05:57,2021-08-22 03:38:55,24.71392833,46.660645,24.7097,46.66272,0.67
18724,476,32291,65,2021-08-22 03:14:37,2021-08-22 04:18:56,24.77137833,46.64568667,24.7722,46.64523167,32.35
```

and here's the desired output

```
{
    "38579": {
        "18721": {
        "scooterId": "927",
        "userId": "38579",
        "totalDuration": "45",
        "pickUpTime": "2021-08-22 03:00:49",
        "dropOffTime": "2021-08-22 03:45:39",
        "userLocationAtBooking.0": "24.76412",
        "userLocationAtBooking.1": "46.6493",
        "userLocationAtDropOff.0": "24.76409833",
        "userLocationAtDropOff.1": "46.64934",
        "totalFare": "9.58"
        }
    },
    "38563": {
        "18722" : {
        "scooterId": "434",
        "userId": "38563",
        "totalDuration": "45",
        "pickUpTime": "2021-08-22 03:01:16",
        "dropOffTime": "2021-08-22 03:45:39",
        "userLocationAtBooking.0": "24.76412",
        "userLocationAtBooking.1": "46.64933333",
        "userLocationAtDropOff.0": "24.76407",
        "userLocationAtDropOff.1": "46.64933333",
        }
    }
}
```

but here's what I'm getting

```
{
    "38563": {
        "tripId": "18722",
        "scooterId": "434",
        "userId": "38563",
        "totalDuration": "45",
        "pickUpTime": "2021-08-22 03:01:16",
        "dropOffTime": "2021-08-22 03:45:39",
        "userLocationAtBooking.0": "24.76412",
        "userLocationAtBooking.1": "46.64933333",
        "userLocationAtDropOff.0": "24.76407",
        "userLocationAtDropOff.1": "46.64933333",
        "totalFare": "13.53"
    }
}
```

and here's the code I'm currently using

```
import csv, json
csvFilePath = 'tripsData.csv'
jsonFilePath = 'tripsData.json'

data = {}
with open(csvFilePath) as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for rows in csvReader:
        id = rows['userId']
        data[id] = rows
    for rows in csvReader:
        tripId = rows[tripId]
        data[tripId] = rows

with open(jsonFilePath, 'w') as jsonFile:
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

ANy help would be highly appreciated and please keep in mind I'm really new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading from the file two times, but first for-loop already exhausted the `csvReader`. To get desired output, you can use next example:

```py
import csv, json

csvFilePath = "tripsData.csv"
jsonFilePath = "tripsData.json"

data = {}
with open(csvFilePath, "r") as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for rows in csvReader:
        id_ = rows["userId"]
        data[id_] = rows

    for user_id, row in data.items():
        data[user_id] = {row["tripId"]: row}
        del row["tripId"]


with open(jsonFilePath, "w") as jsonFile:
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Creates json:

```json
{
    "38579": {
        "18721": {
            "scooterId": "927",
            "userId": "38579",
            "totalDuration": "45",
            "pickUpTime": "2021-08-22 03:00:49",
            "dropOffTime": "2021-08-22 03:45:39",
            "userLocationAtBooking.0": "24.76412",
            "userLocationAtBooking.1": "46.6493",
            "userLocationAtDropOff.0": "24.76409833",
            "userLocationAtDropOff.1": "46.64934",
            "totalFare": "9.58"
        }
    },
    "38563": {
        "18722": {
            "scooterId": "434",
            "userId": "38563",
            "totalDuration": "45",
            "pickUpTime": "2021-08-22 03:01:16",
            "dropOffTime": "2021-08-22 03:45:39",
            "userLocationAtBooking.0": "24.76412",
            "userLocationAtBooking.1": "46.64933333",
            "userLocationAtDropOff.0": "24.76407",
            "userLocationAtDropOff.1": "46.64933333",
            "totalFare": "13.53"
        }
    },
    "38554": {
        "18723": {
            "scooterId": "876",
            "userId": "38554",
            "totalDuration": "33",
            "pickUpTime": "2021-08-22 03:05:57",
            "dropOffTime": "2021-08-22 03:38:55",
            "userLocationAtBooking.0": "24.71392833",
            "userLocationAtBooking.1": "46.660645",
            "userLocationAtDropOff.0": "24.7097",
            "userLocationAtDropOff.1": "46.66272",
            "totalFare": "0.67"
        }
    },
    "32291": {
        "18724": {
            "scooterId": "476",
            "userId": "32291",
            "totalDuration": "65",
            "pickUpTime": "2021-08-22 03:14:37",
            "dropOffTime": "2021-08-22 04:18:56",
            "userLocationAtBooking.0": "24.77137833",
            "userLocationAtBooking.1": "46.64568667",
            "userLocationAtDropOff.0": "24.7722",
            "userLocationAtDropOff.1": "46.64523167",
            "totalFare": "32.35"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! but one more thing what if I don't want the userId to show up inside the nest? how can I do that

Comment: @N4VY_B1U3 Add another `del row["userId"]` inside for-loop